# Service able to access file on network when running as specific user, but not as Local System account

Tags: windows-7, permissions, service, local-area-network, local-system

I have a service running on a Win10 client that looks for a txt file within the program's data directory. With a local data directory, finds it no problem.

With data on the network, it's not finding the file. Log file shows me it's looking in the right location *\\server\data* but unable to find *service.txt* in there.
If I change properties on the service to run as my windows account instead of *Local System*, it finds it. So it's a permissions issue of some kind.

I've done as much googling as I can think with no joy, what permissions/attributes should set on from the server on *\data* to let a service running as system access files within it across the network? 
Win 7 machine acting as server, no domain. One thing I found was that permissions in the Sharing tab will take precedence over those in the Security tab when accessed over network, can anyone confirm this?

Tried already: Disabling inheritance and setting security full control: *Everyone, Administrators, Users, Network Service*

Sharing read/write: *Admin, Everyone*

Advanced sharing - permissions full control: *Everyone, Administrators, Users, Network Service*

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permissions to the machine account of the client. MachineName$ is usually the form that takes. Put this in the ntfs permissions and in the share permissions set everyone full control.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Trying to add my MachineName$ in the security tab of data folder properties gives the 'an object named 'MachineName$' could not be found' message. Both machines can see each other across the network, can browse IP and UNC both directions. So what am I missing?

Comment: I should mention, this isn't a domain